# Google Cloud DNS Subdomain Delegation With Separate Zones

Tags: dns, terraform, google-cloud-dns

Using Google Cloud DNS I have **foo.com** DNS Zone setup.
I would like a separate DNS Zone to be delegated responsiblity for **dev**.foo.com domain names ( e.g. myappserver.dev.foo.com could be defined in the delegated DNS zone )

I could of course simply add an A Record into the foo.com definition. But I am using Terraform ( as Infrastructure as code ) and the **dev** subdomain ( servers/records etc ) will be built and destroyed on a regular basis.

The problem is that if I have all this in one DNS Zone that is built/destroyed regularly then this would mean that everything in foo.com would be unstable. I just want anything on dev.foo.com to be unstable from this point of view.

Is this possible? It would seem this would be easy using *different* name servers for dev.foo.com, so I'm assuming it should be okay somehow using the same nameservers but a different DNS Zone. Perhaps something to do with circular dependencies and glue records but I haven't managed to get anything working yet.

Comment: I have a solution of sorts. When using terraform ( or any GCloud client I guess ) the nameservers of a new DNS Managed Zone are "computed" - assigned by Google but without predication. If these Name Servers are different than my parent Zone's then it is a simple case of point **dev**.foo.com to the Name Server's assigned for dev.foo.com Zone.

Comment: From a Terraform point of view I don't want to destroy the sub DNS zone. This is kind of possible using **prevent_destory** although there is an outstanding bug ( See https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3874 ). In meantime I can split up terraform project into **transient** and **sticky/permenant** sub projects in order to get the behaviour I want.    I will confirm later if this works as expected.

Comment: So yeah, splitting out the terraform projects into "enduring" and "ephemeral" means that only when I run the "enduring" porject ( i.e. assign new Name Servers to dev.foo.com ) do I then need to manually update these in the parent DNS entry. Rest is automated after that so consider me happy :-)

Comment: +1 for using Terraform, it's great. Terraform shouldn't need to create/destroy the subzone when you are making changes, it can just update the record sets (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_record_set.html) to match. Even in the case where you are creating a project from scratch with a main and delegated subzones, it should be possible to automate this, as you can use the [name_servers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/dns_managed_zone.html#name_servers) attribute to get the name servers for the subzone and create a corresponding NS record in the parent zone.

Comment: If you can post (a link to) a simple sample TF file that sets up the parent and child zones, I could probably suggest an edit to automate the NS record set up or other changes that would work a bit better.

Comment: Thanks for comments @AlexDupuy   The parent zone is actually manual in this case ... and some way from being IAC ( because it runs other software ). But that said if I do get there then I hear you on the update option ( i.e. updating the parent ). To be clear only the sub domain is destroyed and recreated - mainly an economical reasons for running VM costs ( but defintely enjoyed getting to use the power of Terraform et al!).   Thanks for your suggestion though and I'll hopefully get to implement in future.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of destroying the `dev` subdomain on a regular basis, delegate it to another nameserver (by including `NS` [and `A` glue!] records for `dev.foo.com`) -- which may also reside at Google, or not, as you wish -- and then have Terraform create and destroy RRs (*Resource Records*, such as `A`, `CNAME`, etc) within the `dev.foo.com` domain.

You shouldn't need to destroy and recreate `dev.foo.com`, and if for some reason you do (such as the ability to really test the creation and destruction of records at the level of the main domain itself), use a different domain name altogether such as `foo-test.com`, `foo.io`, etc.